# How to use props as component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where I receive props that include a Link component (of React router, but could be anything):

```
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      isActive: false,
      label: 'Forms',
      icon: <DestinationsIcon height={30} width={30} />,
      link: <Link to={'somewhere'} />,
    },
```

Then in the component receiving those props I can extract the props form the children:

```
  <List>
    {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
      if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return null;
      }
      return React.cloneElement(child, {
        children: <div>{child.props.label}</div>,
      });
    })}
  </List>
```

The `child.props.label` does return the correct label for example. However what I'd like to do is replace that wrapping `<div>` with the `link` props, something like this:

```
children: <child.props.link>{child.props.label}</child.props.link>,
```

This of course doesn't work. If I'm trying with React.createElement:

```
children: React.createElement(child.props.link),
```

The first argument should be a string, but I'm passing a component. The thing is that I must receive the Link component from outside with its own context, and I cannot re-create it, otherwise I could avoid all the complexity.

Does anyone know what would be the correct way to render that link props as a JSX wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `link: <Link to={'somewhere'} />` prop **isn't** a component, it's an element. This is what it would look like as a component: `link: Link` (and then you'd need to pass the props for `Link` separately, perhaps as `linkProps`):

```
children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      isActive: false,
      label: 'Forms',
      icon: <DestinationsIcon height={30} width={30} />,
      link: Link,                     // ***
      linkProps: {to: 'somewhere'},   // ***
    },
```

Then, to use it, you need to be referencing it via an identifier with an upper case first character, since that's how React/JSX differentiate between tags (like `div` or `svg`) and components.

So something along these lines:

```
const Link = child.props.link;
return React.cloneElement(child, {
    children: <Link {...child.props.linkProps}>{child.props.label}</Link>,
});
```

...although that may need tweaking as it's not clear to me why you're doing the extracting and cloning.

Here's a simpler example showing using a component as a prop:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = ({ link: Link, linkProps, label }) => {
    return <Link {...linkProps}>{label}</Link>;
};

const SomeNiftyLink = ({ href, className, children }) => (
    <a href={href} className={className}>
        {children}
    </a>
);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Example
            link={SomeNiftyLink}
            linkProps={{
                href: "#somewhere",
            }}
            label="The label"
        />
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer yes I did try exactly that, but got the error: 'Element type is invalid; expected a string but got an object'. That happens also when I just test with const Link = <div/>. Do you have an idea why it could happen? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @sir-haver - Did you change what you're passing for `link` as I mentioned in the first paragraph? That's the error you'd get if you didn't. I've added a live example, and updated to add an example of how to change your `children` example just after the first paragraph.